# Loop help in a C++ MPG program

Tags: c++, do-while

I'm stuck in an infinite loop and can't figure out where I went wrong with my below code. I've googled, read & re-read my textbook and still can't figure out where my mistake is. Can someone help point me in the right direction so I can fix this Do-While loop issue?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const double liter = 0.264179;

int main()
{
    double litersOfGas, miles, gallons, mpg;
    char ans;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter the number of liters of gas consumed: \n";
        cin >> litersOfGas;
        cout << "Enter the number of miles driven: \n";
        cin >> miles;
        gallons = (litersOfGas * liter);
        mpg = (miles / gallons);
        cout << litersOfGas << " liters of gasoline consumed, "`enter code here`
            << miles << " miles traveled = " << mpg << " mpg." << endl;

        cout << "Would you like to calculate again (Y/N)?" << endl;
        cin >> ans;
    } while ((ans == 'y') && (ans == 'Y'));


    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The do-while will keep executing until you type in both 'Y' and 'y' in one input stroke. try change it to `while ((ans == 'y') || (ans == 'Y'));`

Comment: From my reading, this loop should never re-execute. No matter what you type, you should exit the loop.

Comment: @GKE is right. Instead of `do-while`, if you use a `while` loop, you need to initialize `ans` to to `y` or `Y`.

Comment: @John You're absolutely correct, I just saw the logical fallacy and pointed it out butif it was the case where ans=='n' or 'N' then then it would be an infinite loop.

Comment: However the root cause of your problem is the `&&` in the condition. `ans` is a character, it cannot be both `y` and `Y` at the same time.

Comment: if the user is getting caught in an infinite loop, then this is most certainly NOT their problem. Either they don't know what an infinite loop is, or this isn't the code they're using.

Comment: Well shoot! I can't believe I overlooked the && operator being wrong. I re-wrote this code so many times and didn't even think to change it. @John you are correct and I missed informed the forum. That was the issue before my last re-type of the code. Thanks to everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your other syntax errors aside, other commentators pointed out that your loop shouldn't be re-evaluating, this is true.

However the case, you cannot have both `Y` and `y` in one character variable, had the options been inverted (and syntax mistakes corrected) this would've resulted in a infinite loop.

```
int main()
{
    char ans;
    do
    {
        cout << "Would you like to calculate again (Y/N)?" << endl;
        cin >> ans;
        if(ans=='y' || ans=='Y') // even if you choose not to continue again, the last statement of a do-while will execute unless you set a condition for it
            cout<<"Going again \n";
    } while ((ans == 'y') || (ans == 'Y')); // ans can be only 'Y' or 'y' , not both

    return 0;
}
```

A while-loop would be more beneficial for your case (based on the code you posted):

```
char ans = 'Y';
while ((ans == 'Y') || (ans == 'y')) {
    cout << "Would you like to calculate again (Y/N)?" << endl;
    cin >> ans;
}
```